# HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode and it just displays android

Tags: android, haxm

after I run the app this is the message I receive and the emulator doesn't display anything.

emulator: device fd:772
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check